# QGIS 3x label is gone when zoom out

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am fighting with the following issue:

I have two labels quite close to each other. When I zoom in everything is alright, but when I zoom out one of them is gone.
See the situation below:

[image]

Is there any way to keep these 2 texts even if they could overlap each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `Label -> Rendering`, there is option to `Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)`, check this option and the labels should appear.

[image]